# Делаю поиск по слову, если находит слово то пишет не нашло, если не находит то ничего не делает.

Tags: php, mysql

Смотрите, хотя if, если есть это слово то выполнять это, а она выполняет елсе

```
if(isset($_POST['uppercasecenders'])){$demostyle = $_POST['uppercasecenders'];}

if(isset($_POST['arealetters'])){$arealetter = $_POST['arealetters'];}

$word = mysql_real_escape_string($demostyle);

$senderlables = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM labels WHERE namelable='$word'");

while($rowlabels = mysql_fetch_array($senderlables)){

    if($demostyle == $rowlabels['namelable']){

        echo 'Отправлено';

    }else{

        echo 'Извините, но лейблов для '.$demostyle.', в базе пока нету';

    }

}
```

Comment: @trix, вы уже месяц на форуме, пора бы уже научиться форматировать код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вы выборкой возвращаете только email, так что ваша проверка `if($demostyle == $rowlabels['namelable']){` ничего не выдаст :)